# Changing from a "View All" to Single View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Just trying to turn this from an (pulls for all records)"all" OnClick to a "single" OnClick. 
This is pulling the data from a gridview so I've added a button on each row that I would like to have pull the data from the row record and query on the specific row. Any help would be appreciated on not having it run the foreach but to get the row-specific data. Thanks.

```
protected void btnViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["id"];
#if DEBUG
    if (id == null)
        id = "111"; // Use my own id for testing locally
#endif
    using (aDataContext dc = new aDataContext())
    {
        var query = (from a in dc.aLists
                     where a.ID == id
                     select new
                     {
                         a.aNumber,
                         a.bNumber,
                         a.cNumber,
                         a.dNumber,
                     }
                         );

        List<aListItem> List = new List<aListItem>();
        foreach (var queryItem in query)
        {
            aList.Add(new aListItem()
            {
                aNumber = queryItem.aNumber,
                bNumber = queryItem.bNumber,
                cNumber = queryItem.cNumber,
                dNumber = queryItem.dNumber
            });
        }
        Session["aList"] = aList;
    }
    Session["Database"] = null;
    Response.Redirect("Viewer.aspx" + "?UseList=true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowDatabound for gridview control, something like :

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}
```

Reference :

> http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We can use the edit template for the GridView, when the button of a row is clicked we can easily get the rowindex from where you can get the ID, then query the data as you want

```
 protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    }
protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


       string id = GridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```

I hope it will helps